# Framework7 modal-overlay tap on iPad calls preventScrolling instead of handleClick

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 inside of React for our view layer. I can get a popover to open and close just fine when viewing my app in Chrome. However, on the iPad I cannot seem to close the modal popover by tapping on the mask. After some debugging, it appears that this line of code within Chrome is where the handleClicks ends up getting called which will then close the modal as it should. 
[ChromeMaskTap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA4lg.jpg)

However, this same exact line of code when debugging on iPad shows preventScrolling as the listener instead of handleClicks. Any ideas on why this could be occuring or what I might be missing?

Comment: It turns out this was all an issue on my end. I was using the Framework7 custom build process and was not including the fast-clicks module. Once I added that to the custom build process it fixed my issue. Sorry to waste everyone's time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was all an issue on my end. I was using the Framework7 custom build process and was not including the fast-clicks module. Once I added that to the custom build process it fixed my issue. Sorry to waste everyone's time!